# $\lim_{k \to \infty} s_k = f(x_0)$ Where $s_k = f(x_0 + \frac{1}{k})$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Proven by the implications from the epsilon delta definition of a continuous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x→∞}f(x)= l $ is equivalente to saying that for every $\epsilon\gt0$, there is a $N>0$ such that if $x>N$ then $|f(x)-l|< \epsilon $.

In this case you don't use the $\delta$, because it's a limit to infinity.

$\lim_{n→∞}f(x_0+\frac{1}{n})= f(x_0) $ implies that for all $\epsilon\gt0$,  there is a $N>0$ such that $n>N \Rightarrow  |f(x_0+\frac{1}{n})-f(x_0)|< \epsilon $

If the function $f(x)$ is continuous, that means that for $a\in D_{f(x)}, \  \lim_{x→a} = f(a)$

Using both definitions (and assuming your function f is continuous) , we know that  $lim_{x→{x_0}} f(x)= f(x_0)$. Now can you prove the equivalence of the limits $\lim_{n→∞}f(x_0+\frac{1}{n})$ and $\lim_{x→{x_0}} f(x)\ $?

(Use the fact that $\lim_{n→∞}f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$ )

Comment: You have it backwards. It should be, if $x>N$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: You are right. Messed it up :(

Comment: It is okay. We all make mistakes :)